# The touchpad randomly stops working

Tags: touchpad, windows-11

I've got a Dell Inspiron 5515, running Windows 11, and after a year of owning it, I've started to get this weird issue where the touchpad clicking stops working randomly (I can still move the mouse around though, just the left/right click cease to work); say after 1h of use. Sometimes it starts working again on its own, for no apparent reason. Sometimes the computer restart helps, and sometimes it doesn't. What I've also noticed is that plugging in, and starting to use an external mouse seems to get it to work again, pretty much always.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Dell site and download the Touchpad (Mouse) Drivers. Reinstall these drivers.

Restart and test the computer.

If drivers are not the solution, you may need to replace the keyboard.

If you are adept at taking a laptop apart, try re-seating the keyboard, or have a local shop do this for you

Likely though, you probably need to replace the keyboard (assuming the touch pad to part of the keyboard assembly).

Do contact Dell to see if warranty is still in effect.